# split string multiple characters without space C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a field that is displayed inside a div and the problem is that it doesn't break line if a user puts in a string thats longer then the number of characters that can fit outside the line within a div, it basically stretches outside the div. How can I insert a space in every word 'thats in a string' that has a seuqence of 20 characters or more without a space between . For example, now I am doing something like this

```
string words
Regex.Replace(words, "(.{" + 20 + "})", "$1" + Environment.NewLine);
```

But that just inserts a line break at every 20 character oppose to a sequence without a space. I am really not that good with regular expressions so the code above is something I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this with regex you could use `@"(\S{20})"` as your pattern.

\S will match any non-whitespace character which I believe fits your criteria since it will then only work if it finds 20 or more non-whitespace characters in a row.

Example usage is:

```
string words = "It should break after \"t\": abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string output = Regex.Replace(words, @"(\S{20})", "$1" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: So how do I change that line of code I put in my question, as I said I am not good with regex: Regex.Replace(words, @"\S{20}", "$1" + Environment.NewLine);

Comment: I've added in an example and clarified my first line which should indeed have `()` to capture the contents of the match for use with the `$1`.

Answer (score 2):

Would a CSS solution work better?

`word-wrap:break-word;`

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/45Fq4/

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the regex question specifically, I just think maybe the question is assuming the wrong solution to the problem.

Comment: I'd say it answers the problem as stated in the first sentence. You're just doing it in a different way but in what looks like the best way.

Comment: Please don't link [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/). Try [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) instead.

Comment: @Romoku: You shouldn't say that without references for why. I've seen them before myself but for anybody that hasn't you're just sounding silly. :)

Comment: no that doesn't work..I guess  cause I didnt mention that this is a mobile view so that would cause more problems then fix

Comment: @Jake OK, not sure why that would matter but clearly there's more going on. Hopefully the regex split will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me:

```
string words
string outputwords = words;
int CharsWithoutSpace = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < outputwords.Length; i++)
{
     if (outputwords[i] == ' ')
     {
         CharsWithoutSpace = 0;
     }
     else
     {
         CharsWithoutSpace++;
         if (CharsWithoutSpace >= 20)
         {
             outputwords = outputwords.Insert(i + 1, Environment.NewLine);
             CharsWithoutSpace = 0;
         }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(outputwords);
```